# How can I copy text to clipboard with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React web app that converts a text into an array. I want the user to click on the final output and be able to copy it on the clipboard.

I am following the of many websites and tutorial. I am very new to ReactJS and I don't know what's wrong with my code!

This is the function I

```
copyToClipboard() {
const {array} = this.state

const textToCopy = "const myArray =" + JSON.stringify(array)

textToCopy.select()
document.execCommand("copy")

this.setState({copySuccess: true})
}
```

The function is called by this button. The button works fine:

```
      <button onClick={this.copyToClipboard.bind(this)} id="copy-to-clipboard" className="btn btn-normal">Copy to clipboard</button>
```

I think the problem is in this part of the function below, but I don't know how to fix it!

```
textToCopy.select()
document.execCommand("copy")
```

Link to the whole app + code:

https://codepen.io/Nerdifico/pen/MWKPdNX?editors=0010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a DOM element from which to copy from. [This](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/blog/s/copy-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript) is an example with textarea. You can't call select on string value.

Answer (score 7):

```
const copyToClipboard = (content: any) => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = content;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
};
```

Here is my solution, it contains 3 steps:

- Create an empty textarea element
- Assign the value your want to copy to it and exec copy command
- Remove the textarea you have created

Answer (score 1):

As @Rosen mentioned you should use copy on DOM element

Something like this

```
 <textarea
        ref={(textarea) => this.textArea = textarea}
        value='Some text to copy'
      />
```

and then in your function call it

```
copyToClipboard = (e) => {
    this.textArea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const CopyTextIcon: React.FC = () => {
  function copyToClipboard() {
    const tempInput = document.createElement('input')
    tempInput.value = 'text'
    document.body.appendChild(tempInput)
    tempInput.select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    document.body.removeChild(tempInput)
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={()=>copyToClipboard('topRight')}>
       <img src="/images/ic-SHARE.svg" alt="share" />
    </div>
  )
}
```